# Tomcat cannot open database using jdbc after upgrading to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, tomcat7

I successfully connected to my database when it was SQL Server 2008 R2.
However after upgrading to SQL Server 2012, I get the following error in my java code
The application server that I am using is Tomcat7

The error is as follows:

```
Jun 10, 2012 1:56:10 PM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
```

The connection string in context.xml is

```
<Resource name="jdbc/theDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" initialSize="30"
            maxActive="100"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyDB;integratedSecurity=true"
            />
```

The following is in web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
<description>My Database</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/theDB</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I can connect successfully to the database by opening a Data Connection in Eclipse, and in the fact the connection string that is generated is identical to the url from context.xml that I reproduce above.

Has anyone any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the user running the application server have sufficient rights to the databas?

Comment: Hi Mark. Are user rights relevant if I use `integratedSecurity=true` (as in the URL above). Thank you

Comment: Of course it is, `integratedSecurity` means that the Windows user running the application server is used for authorization on the SQL server. If that user does not have any rights to the DB it will not be able to open it.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you for your comment. I am logged in as user administrator and I went to Users and added New User/administrator.  I am still getting the same error. (I will look at this direction a bit more over the next couple of days...) However why could I connect with Eclipse without any problem? Thank you...

Comment: Eclipse is probably running under a different user than your application server.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks... I am - to the best of my knowledge - using the 'Administrator' user for both Eclipse and the Tomcat Application Server.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you... I should have right-clicked the service for the service for the Application Server, and selected Properties and Logon and then set the user to be 'Administrator'... It now works great! Can you post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you the user that is running the application server has sufficient rights to the database.